# Using Devise/DatabaseAuthenticatable module to check password/salt a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm building an app that uses Devise to manage user state. I'm also building an API in that same app that receives a username and password from a POST request

What I'm trying to accomplish is:

- Get the user by username from the database (done, straightforward)
- Use `Devise::Models::DatabaseAuthenticatable` to take the password the user passed in, encrypt it, compare it against the `encrypted_password` field on the User model and if they're the same, proceed with the rest of my code

The second bullet above is what I'm having trouble with. In a console, I can't seem to get an instance of the module `Devise::Models::DatabaseAuthenticatable` to try the various instance methods that you can find here in the [docs](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/DatabaseAuthenticatable).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you can use [.valid_password?](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Models/DatabaseAuthenticatable#valid_password%3F-instance_method) devise method. Something like that:

```
#assuming you'll receive nested params like user[email], user[password]...
user_params = params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password)

user = User.find_by(email: user_params[:email])
return head 403 if user.nil?
valid = user.valid_password?(user_params[:password]) #true or false...
return head 403 unless valid

sign_in(user) #devise helper: if you want to sign in that user
```

You can also check another approachs, like [devise token auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth) gem.

Comment: Ah, so easy. Thanks mrlew